# Require JS error In IE unable to resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

[image]

Below is require JS config file

```
//require JS configuration file start
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'Libraries/JQuery/jquery',
        'jqueryui': 'Libraries/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui',
        'sweetalert': 'Libraries/SweetAlert/sweetalert2.all',
        'datatables': 'Libraries/DataTables/datatables',
        'datatables.net': 'Libraries/DataTables/datatables.min',
        'es6promise': 'Libraries/Polyfill/es6-promise.auto',
        'zingchart': 'Libraries/zingchart/zingchart.min',
        'bootstrap': 'Libraries/bootstrap-3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap',
    },
    shim: {
        'jqueryui': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'sweetalert': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'datatables': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'datatables.net': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'script': {
            deps: ['datatables.net']
        }

    },
    waitSeconds: 7

});

//End of the require js config file

Main JS file

define(['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'sweetalert', 'datatables', 'es6promise', 'zingchart', 'bootstrap'], function ($, jqueryui, swal, datatables, es6promise, z_chart) {

});

//End of Main JS file.
```

-----Html File----

[image]

----End Of Html File----

1. I am not getting any error in google chrome.
2. I am getting the error only in IE and unable to resolve it, also tried so hard.
3. Whenever I remove "bootstrap" in the main JS define module everything works fine, but whenever I am including "bootstrap" in the main define module and then I am getting the error that is there in the first picture.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check which file has this line: `return factory( $, window, document ); }`? This seems to be loaded via <script> tag but it has call to `define()` inside. That is why you have this error. Maybe you have some IE-only javascript and that might cause the issue

Comment: in my code, I have nowhere something like this ```return factory( $, window, document ); }```

You can see in the above I have added one more picture which is my HTML, Please let me know where should I update this